# JavaScript: Check for existence of key in nested objects when its path is unknown

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if a key exists in my object.

I don't know where or on which nested object the key could be specifically, I just know the name of the key (or property). It would be very handy for me to have a function allowing to quickly search the object and determine if the property key exists in the object.

To illustrate this, my mock object would be something like this:

```
const testObject = {
  one : {
    two : {
      three : "hello"
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect that a function to find if a key exists would return `true` for a property key of `"three"` or `"one"`, and would return `false` for a key of `"fooBar"`

I have tried the `hasOwnProperty` method but it fails.

Comment: If you don't need the value, a simple `JSON.stringify(nestedObjects).indexOf('"thePropName":') !== -1` would probably work.

Comment: Note that `JSON.stringify` will remove the key if its value isn't serializable, like a Function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be with a recursive search function like `doesObjectHaveNestedKey()` as shown below ( which this does not require an extra dependency like lodash ):

```js
const object = {
  some : {
    nested : {
      property : {
        to : [
          {
            find : {
              foo : [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

/* Define function to recursively search for existence of key in obj */
function doesObjectHaveNestedKey(obj, key) {

  if(obj === null || obj === undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  
  for(const k of Object.keys(obj)) {
  
    if(k === key) {
      /* Search keys of obj for match and return true if match found */
      return true
    }
    else {
      const val = obj[k];
      
      /* If k not a match, try to search it's value. We can search through
      object value types, seeing they are capable of containing
      objects with keys that might be a match */
      if(typeof val === 'object') {
      
        /* Recursivly search for nested key match in nested val */
        if(doesObjectHaveNestedKey(val, key) === true) {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}

console.log('has foo?', doesObjectHaveNestedKey(object, 'foo') )        // True
console.log('has bar?', doesObjectHaveNestedKey(object, 'bar') )        // False
console.log('has nested?', doesObjectHaveNestedKey(object, 'nested') )  // True
console.log('has cat?', doesObjectHaveNestedKey(null, 'cat') )          // False
```

The idea here is to:

1. look through the keys of the input object "obj" for a key "k" that matches the input "key"
2. if a match is found return true, otherwise
3. look for any value "val" of "obj" that is able to store nested objects (Explore "Object" types as only these can store nested keys) and
4. recursively search a "val" of those types for a match and if found, return true

Comment: thanks for your answer, it returns me:   "message": "ReferenceError: hasKey is not defined",

Comment: Sorry I was renaming the function and updated the answer, does it work now?

Comment: That´s because there's no function hasKey defined, change it for the defined function ```doesObjectHavenestedKey```

Comment: @Webwoman sorry for the confusion, I was just making an edit to the answer to try and improve the clarity - have tested it's working. please reload to see the updates :)

Comment: `typeof` will never return "array". Arrays are of type "object". Also `=== true` is superfluous. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: `typeof null === "object"` which will make this fail on an input of `{ whatever: null }`.

Comment: @EmileBergeron thanks for that, so for instance are you saying that the current solution would incorrectly return `false` for `doesObjectHaveNestedKey({ foo : { bar : null }}, 'bar')`?

Comment: Not if you're searching for `bar`. But if the key is not found and `doesObjectHaveNestedKey` gets called with the `null` value, it will throw.

Comment: @EmileBergeron thanks for that, I added an extra check to ensure `obj` is an accessible object

Answer (score 3):

The answer of Dacre Denny could also be written as:

```
  const hasKey = (obj, key) => 
    Object.keys(obj).includes(key) ||
    Object.values(obj)
      .filter(it => typeof it === "object" && it !== null)
      .some(it => hasKey(it, key));
```

Comment: `typeof null === "object"` which will make this fail on an input of `{ whatever: null }`.

Comment: @emile indeed, fixed :)

Comment: Not sure if it's the wanted behaviour from OP, but arrays will be traversed as well since `typeof [] === "object"` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another recursive function. If the current `obj` is an object, look if its **keys** `includes` the target key. If isn't included, recall the function for each `obj` value:

```
const searchKey = (obj, key) => 
    obj && typeof obj === "object" &&
    (Object.keys(obj).includes(key) ||
    Object.values(obj).some(o => searchKey(o, key)));
```

##### Try the snippet

```js
const testObject = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: "hello"
    }
  },
  foo: {
    bar: {
      foobar: 10
    }
  }
}

const searchKey = (obj, key) => 
    obj && typeof obj === "object" &&
    (Object.keys(obj).includes(key) ||
    Object.values(obj).some(o => searchKey(o, key)));


console.log(searchKey(testObject, "two")); //true
console.log(searchKey(testObject, "foo")); //true
console.log(searchKey(testObject, "barfoo")); //false
console.log(searchKey(testObject, "foobar")); //true
```